# Is it possible to change the background color of just one tabbaritem?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, tintcolor

I want to change just one of my tabs' background colors. I also want to change only one of their tint colors. How would I do this using Swift?

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
var tabBarItems = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items as Array<UITabBarItem>
tabBarItems[0]....?
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I created a button and covered the tabbaritem with it.